# Partitioning after Windows to Ubuntu migration

Tags: partitioning, disk

As will be apparent from my question I am quite new at Linux.
I migrated from Windows7 to Linux[Ubuntu]. After the installation was over, I figured out that all the partitions have been overridden and now only a single partition exists.
Is there any way to create partitions now?

[image: Disk Manger]
[image: GParted]

Comment: use https://imgur.com to upload screenshots. Could you add a screenshot of GParted in Ubuntu?

Comment: Gparted is showing LUKS or LVM. Did you install full drive LVM or full drive encryption install options, not standard MBR or gpt partitions. Gparted does not work on LVM partitions.

Comment: gparted image : http://i.imgur.com/zOFbhrB.png

Comment: If you're indeed new to Linux, I recommend, that you stay away from the Logical Volume Manager and, if possible, full disk encryption in the beginning. LVM provides little advantage over regular disk partitioning to the average Linux desktop user, but much more complexity. eCryptfs provides a well working overlay encryption for your home directory, if you need it. Since this is a new installation, it would be most simple to re-install Ubuntu without LVM and encryption.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: There are two partitions, not one.

And yes, you can change the partitions. Boot a live system (so the hard drive isn't accessed) and open GParted. Resize the big partition from the right and you have space for more partitions. Resizing it from the left to the right is also possible, however, this will take *a lot* longer since all data has to be copied.

It is also important to mention that changing something on your partitions always comes with a risk, especially if there is a power failure and you're not working on a laptop with a battery or behind an uninterruptible power supply.

Comment: can you please help me understand how come there is a partition of 243mb showing up and other two partitions of 698.40 MB each in gparted, as i have not defined anything explicitly during installation?  http://i.imgur.com/zOFbhrB.png

Comment: Post the output of `df -h`. Since these are comments, please use pastebin.

Comment: sorry pastebin is not allowing me to paste images, here is the screenshot http://i.imgur.com/4DlyOmv.png  sincere apologies for sharing link again

Comment: Unfortunately it's not so easy, since OP is using LVM and LUKS.

Comment: Usually command line output is postet as text. You can copy text from the terminal. ;-) Look at the last line of the output. There you have the reason for the small partition on the left: It's your boot partition. You can see this because it's mounted on `/boot`. A boot partition is needed for full disk encryption, so don't delete it. Resizing your encrypted partition is much harder than resizing a non-encrypted one. Follow these instructions: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ResizeEncryptedPartitions

Comment: Also make your sure your laptop is plugged in, otherwise the battery may become empty before the moving process is ready.